# Regex to parse the address in one string array element and invoice

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me with regular expression in php please .
I want print the first word in the first line and in the second line first word like the text document below

```
4 newland Avenue.                  Invoice 0004
          London
          W3 1lg
```

Result needs to be something like

```
"Address" => "4 newland  Avenue London W3 1lg",
"Invoice" => "0004"
 etc...
```

I need an expression to escape the invoice number since its in the same line of the first line of the address

I really appreciate your help and thanks in advance

Comment: you should probably mention the range of possible invoice numbers. Is it always of length 4 digits? Only digits possible?

Comment: When asking for help on SO, it's best to show what code you have tried, and where you ran into difficulty. SO isn't a code writing service, so you're much more likely to get help when you show your effort. REGEX: I find **online regex testers** to be invaluable when writing and debugging regex expressions.  You can google for "php regex tester".  For example **(https://regex101.com/)** which also has php specific documentation. Or **(http://www.phpliveregex.com/)**.  Also check out the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Please post your code with the sample input assigned to a variable. This way we will know exactly what the whitespaces are in the text.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the invoice number only, assuming they are always 4 digits and the document is formatted just as you have shown... you can use the following regex.

/\b[Ii]nvoice (\d{4})\b/

In PHP you will likely use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the invoice number.

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/PGiRQW/3): Notice that only the digit is in the capture group and that this regex will ONLY match 4 digits that are preceded by the words "invoice" or "Invoice."

Comment: What about the address?

Comment: @entio can you use https://regex101.com and give us a test string to work with... with multiple addresses in the exact format as in your file.

Comment: @philipweber how the hell should i know what should it be? Im just moderating the question dude, and pointing out that your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @entio Chill, I thought you were the OP... my bad. It's not really possible to group both without knowing more about the data. :(

Comment: @philipweber chill, chill, didnt wanna offend you! Sorry if i did. You're totally right that it's not possible to find a better answer with the current data.